# Creating a Function Representation for Environments in SML

Tags: sml

Okay, So I am working on creating a function representation for environments in SML:

```
type name = string
type 'a fenv = name -> 'a
```

I'm a little stuck on how to proceed with this. The first thing I need to do is define a value fenvEmpty of type 'a fenv, which represents the empty environment (the environment that does not bind any names). So far, I have this:

```
val fenvEmpty = 
    let
        fun empty (name) = ???
    in
        empty
    end
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or anything. What am I supposed to return from the function empty? Putting in 0, null, or NONE won't work.

Later, I also have to write functions that returns data associated with a particular name in the environment (a find function), and a function that binds data to a particular name in the environment ( a bind function), but I'm already stuck on the fenvEmpty part.

Comment: Shouldn't `fenv` have return type `'a option`?

Comment: No, specifications require that it return 'a

Comment: Do the specifications say anything about what should be returned when the argument is a name that's not set in the environment?

Comment: It didnt mention, but a classmate hinted to me that it should raise an exception. So I changed it to a lambda function inside the value that raises a NotFound name exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the teacher wants you to `raise` an exception when attempting to look up an unbound value:

```
type name = string
type 'a fenv = name -> 'a

exception UnboundName of name

fun fenvEmpty name = raise UnboundName name
```

But I think it will help you more if you first try to use a version of `fenv` that returns `NONE` for unbound variables. I believe this because, as opposed to exceptions, there's more type structure to the program that will guide you while writing the implementation (see also below). So, first try to write this implementation where `fenv` is:

```
type 'a fenv = name -> 'a option
```

Now, for the later part of the question, you'll have to define a function for associating a `name` with a `value` to an existing environment. This would be that function's type:

```
val fenvAssoc : 'a fenv -> name -> 'a -> 'a fenv
```

Notice that the above returns a result of type `'a fenv`. But remember what `fenv` actually is. It's "just" a function:

```
type 'a fenv = name -> 'a
```

So, this returned value, a function, needs to somehow "remember" the `name` and `value` that have been associated with it. How do functions normally "remember" things they've "seen" in the context where they've been defined?

To look up a name's value, you need a third function, which takes an existing environment and a name and returns the value for that name, if any:

```
val fenvLookup : 'a fenv -> name -> 'a
```

Again, remember what the type of `'a fenv` is:

```
type 'a fenv = name -> 'a
```

I'm emphasizing this because the type of `'a fenv` restricts you in the operations you can apply to it. You can basically either: a) create a function or b) apply one.

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanations. It turns out that he did indeed want an exception to be raised, so I got that part done.

Comment: Are you possibly saying to return a function closure? Becuase when I think of it for the bind I'm confused as to how we can bind the name and value to the existing environment.

Comment: @laughingllama42 yes, that's what I'm saying. When binding new identifiers (using `fenvAssoc`), the returned closure has access to the name and value received by `fenvAssoc`. It also has access to the previous env. So later on, when sometimes calls this closure, it can do two things: 1) verify the name it got to the one it has in its closure, or 2) delegate this check to the previous closure. It's a stack of closures. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the recap especially on such an old post